# The probability that data is biased

Tags: probability

I have over 1800 spins on a roulette wheel and the theoretical probability of number of winning spins based on the number of numbers bet is .4957, but the experimental probability is actually .5358 (based on a strategy I have been working on). How do I calculate if the results are luck or does my strategy work?

Comment: Can you mention how many numbers are on the wheel and how you make your choices?  It doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @MichaelChernick What difference does the number of stopping places on the wheel make?

Comment: It determines what a random spin would be.

Comment: 1. Presumably you're talking about a nominally 50-50 bet like red/black even/odd or 1-18/19-36 ... but 0.4957 winning probability won't be correct for any table I've seen; they'll either be 18/37 or 18/38. What roulette bet theoretically returns this? Are you sure you're counting equally likely events? ... 2. It's unclear in what sense the *data* would be biased. You presumably mean that the data might show that the wheel is not fair (not giving equally likely basic outcomes)

Answer (score 3):

So you spin the wheel 1800 times, and win 53.58% of the time. Let's say that's 964 wins. Theoretically, you expected 49.57% of spins, or 892 of them, to win. Using the Binomial distribution, we can get the P-value of the result as the probability of getting 964 wins or more assuming the true probability of success is 49.57.

$$P(X \geq 964 | n=1800, p = 0.4957) = 1 - P(X < 964 | n=1800, p = 0.4957)$$

Using your favorite software, you should find the P-value is approximately $0.0003$. This implies that there is some evidence that your success rate is indeed higher than 49.57%.

Comment: +1 re the interpretation: another possible implication (and far more likely, IMHO) is that the 49.57% value is a miscalculation.  That is because there is no roulette wheel in any casino anywhere that has such a high theoretical chance of winning, regardless of the bet.